# Google Drive Android API how to upload a audio file to my drive ? How to sync drive files?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I have gone through Demo's but I tried with the QuickStart example  in which a image is uploaded. but I am not getting how to upload a audio file in which i will give path to my files or Intent Picker to select the file.I am using **createFile()** method

1. how to upload a audio file to my drive?

   - I need to convert it to any streams ?

     - why google has made this so much complicated just to upload file?
2. How to Synch Drive files ?
3. How to stream (play audio file from drive)?

**The Below code just upload file which contains nothing.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
    OnConnectionFailedListener {

private static final String TAG = "android-drive-quickstart";
//private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CAPTURE_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;
private static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 3;
private static final int PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE = 1;
private static Uri fileUri;
private ContentsResult result;
private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
private Bitmap mBitmapToSave;


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
        // Create the API client and bind it to an instance variable.
        // We use this instance as the callback for connection and connection
        // failures.
        // Since no account name is passed, the user is prompted to choose.
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();
    }
    // Connect the client. Once connected, the camera is launched.
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}




@Override
public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
    // Called whenever the API client fails to connect.
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
    if (!result.hasResolution()) {
        // show the localized error dialog.
        showToast("Error in on connection failed");
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 0).show();
        return;
    }
    // The failure has a resolution. Resolve it.
    // Called typically when the app is not yet authorized, and an
    // authorization
    // dialog is displayed to the user.
    try {
        result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
        showToast("error"+e.toString());
        Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
    }
}


@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.i(TAG, "API client connected.");

    showToast("Inside Connected");
    result = Drive.DriveApi.newContents(mGoogleApiClient).await();

    showToast(""+result.getContents().toString());
    OutputStream outputStream = result.getContents().getOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //java.io.File fileContent = new java.io.File(fileUri.getPath());


    MetadataChangeSet changeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
    .setTitle("New file")
    .setMimeType("audio/MP3")
    .setStarred(true).build();
    showToast("meta data created");
    DriveFileResult dfres= Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient())
    .createFile(getGoogleApiClient(), changeSet, result.getContents())
    .await();
    showToast("await() complete");
    if (!result.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        showToast("Error while trying to create the file");
        return;
    }
    showToast("Created a file: " + dfres.getDriveFile().getDriveId());
}



private void saveFileToDrive()
{

}


@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        showToast("Connected");
    }
}



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
    super.onPause();
}


public void showToast(final String toast) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
  }

public GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
    return mGoogleApiClient;
  }

@Override
public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
**
 * An AsyncTask that maintains a connected client.
 */
public abstract class ApiClientAsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>
        extends AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result> {

    private GoogleApiClient mClient;

    public ApiClientAsyncTask(Context context) {
        GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE);
        mClient = builder.build();
    }

    @Override
    protected final Result doInBackground(Params... params) {
        Log.d("TAG", "in background");
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        mClient.registerConnectionCallbacks(new ConnectionCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
        mClient.registerConnectionFailedListener(new OnConnectionFailedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult arg0) {
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });
        mClient.connect();
        try {
            latch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            return null;
        }
        if (!mClient.isConnected()) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return doInBackgroundConnected(params);
        } finally {
            mClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Override this method to perform a computation on a background thread, while the client is
     * connected.
     */
    protected abstract Result doInBackgroundConnected(Params... params);

    /**
     * Gets the GoogleApliClient owned by this async task.
     */
    protected GoogleApiClient getGoogleApiClient() {
        return mClient;
    }
    }
```

**Class to save file:**

```
 /**
     * An async task that creates a new text file by creating new contents and
     * metadata entities on user's root folder. A number of blocking tasks are
     * performed serially in a thread. Each time, await() is called on the
     * result which blocks until the request has been completed.
     */
public class CreateFileAsyncTask extends ApiClientAsyncTask<String, Void, Metadata>
{

    public CreateFileAsyncTask(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected Metadata doInBackgroundConnected(String... arg0)
    {
        // First we start by creating a new contents, and blocking on the
        // result by calling await().
        DriveApi.ContentsResult contentsResult = Drive.DriveApi.newContents(getGoogleApiClient()).await();

        if (!contentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            // We failed, stop the task and return.
            return null;
        }

        //file to save in drive
        String pathFile = arg0[0];
        File file = new File(pathFile);

        // Read the contents and open its output stream for writing, then
        // write a short message.
        Contents originalContents = contentsResult.getContents();
        OutputStream os = originalContents.getOutputStream();

        try
        {
            InputStream dbInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int length;
            int counter = 0;
            while((length = dbInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0)
            {
                ++counter;
                os.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }

            dbInputStream.close();
            os.flush();
            os.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }

        // Create the metadata for the new file including title and MIME
        // type.
        MetadataChangeSet originalMetadata = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
        .setTitle(file.getName())
        .setMimeType("application/x-sqlite3").build();

        // Create the file in the root folder, again calling await() to
        // block until the request finishes.
        DriveFolder rootFolder = Drive.DriveApi.getRootFolder(getGoogleApiClient());
        DriveFolder.DriveFileResult fileResult = rootFolder.createFile(
        getGoogleApiClient(), originalMetadata, originalContents).await();

        if (!fileResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            // We failed, stop the task and return.
            return null;
        }

        // Finally, fetch the metadata for the newly created file, again
        // calling await to block until the request finishes.
        DriveResource.MetadataResult metadataResult = fileResult.getDriveFile()
        .getMetadata(getGoogleApiClient())
        .await();

        if (!metadataResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            // We failed, stop the task and return.
            return null;
        }
        // We succeeded, return the newly created metadata.
        return metadataResult.getMetadata();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Metadata result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        if (result == null)
        {
            // The creation failed somehow, so show a message.
            App.showAppMsg(getActivity(),"Error while creating the file.",Style.ALERT);
            return;
        }
        // The creation succeeded, show a message.
        App.showAppMsg(getActivity(),"File created: " + result.getDriveId(),Style.CONFIRM);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't played with audio files, but in general, the Google Drive Android API (GDAA) does not deal with audio files per say. You just create a file, set metadata and stuff binary content in it. Look at the [code here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/140201-GDAA/blob/master/awaits/MainActivity.java) (plus some [readme blah blah here](https://github.com/seanpjanson/140201-GDAA)). You'll find a code line

```
 byte[] buff = ("written on: " + _dfn.getName()).getBytes();
 if (null == _gc.creatFile(fldr, name, MIMETEXT, buff))  return;
```

there, that produces *byte[]* buffer and creates a file with text MIME type. So, try to use it, just replace the MIME type and stuff the 'buff' with your audio stream. I do it successfully with JPEG binaries.

There is also *GooApiClnt* wrapper class there that handles most of the basic GDAA functions. *Don't try to code this way at work, though, it may get you fired :-)*.

Good luck.

Comment: Your both the links are not working. Can you update?

Answer (score 1):

In your onConnected method you create the new file, but you never put any new content in it. You create the new content in this line:

```
result = Drive.DriveApi.newContents(mGoogleApiClient).await();
```

Than you get a hold of it's output stream in this line:

```
OutputStream outputStream = result.getContents().getOutputStream();
```

And than you create an empty byte array output stream in this line:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
```

But you never fill this 'bitmapStream' with any content, and worst: you never write it to your content's 'outputStream'.

What you should do next is write your audio file's contents to 'bitmapStream' something like this:

```
InputStream in = file.getInputStream(/*you need to get the file's path and put it here*/ "some_audio_file.mp3");
int singleByte;
while((singleByte = in.read()) != -1){
   bitmapStream.write(b);
}
```

Now you'd have your file's content inside 'bitmapStrea' and you can write it to the new content's 'outputStream' like this:

```
outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
```

Than you do the 'MetadataChangeSet' stuff and you should be fine.

Some advices:
 1. It is not a good practice to do I/O operations like file or network activities (or file AND network activities in your case) on the main thread. Better use an AsyncTask to do it in a background thread.

1. Don't call your ByteArrayOutputStream instance 'bitmapStream' if you use it to upload an audio file.

Here's an example of a class that uses an AsyncTask to upload an image (and guess what I called the ByteArrayOutputStream... right - 'bitmapStream'):

```
public class TakePhotoActivity extends Activity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    /**
     * Request code for auto Google Play Services error resolution.
     */
    protected static final int REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "TakePhotoActivity";
    private static final String KEY_IN_RESOLUTION = "is_in_resolution";
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR = 2;

    /**
     * Google API client.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    /**
     * Receives the new file's contents and executes the editor AsyncTask
     */
    private ResultCallback<DriveApi.ContentsResult> mSaveFileCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.ContentsResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(DriveApi.ContentsResult contentsResult) {
            EditFileAsyncTask editFileAsyncTask = new EditFileAsyncTask();
            editFileAsyncTask.execute(contentsResult);
        }
    };

    /**
     * Determines if the client is in a resolution state, and
     * waiting for resolution intent to return.
     */
    private boolean mIsInResolution;

    private Bitmap mBitmapToSave;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is starting. Restores the activity state.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_take_menu_photo);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mIsInResolution = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(KEY_IN_RESOLUTION, false);
        }

        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("some_image.jpg");
            mBitmapToSave = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when the Activity is made visible.
     * A connection to Play Services need to be initiated as
     * soon as the activity is visible. Registers {@code ConnectionCallbacks}
     * and {@code OnConnectionFailedListener} on the
     * activities itself.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addApi(Drive.API)
                    .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                            // Optionally, add additional APIs and scopes if required.
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .build();
        }
        Log.d("test", "connect()");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    /**
     * Called when activity gets invisible. Connection to Play Services needs to
     * be disconnected as soon as an activity is invisible.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
        super.onStop();
    }

    /**
     * Saves the resolution state.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(KEY_IN_RESOLUTION, mIsInResolution);
    }

    /**
     * Handles Google Play Services resolution callbacks.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION:
                retryConnecting();
                break;
        }
    }

    private void retryConnecting() {
        mIsInResolution = false;
        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
            Log.d("test", "connect()");
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is connected.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connected");
        // TODO: Start making API requests.
        if (mBitmapToSave != null) {
            saveFileToDrive();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} connection is suspended.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection suspended");
        retryConnecting();
    }

    /**
     * Called when {@code mGoogleApiClient} is trying to connect but failed.
     * Handle {@code result.getResolution()} if there is a resolution
     * available.
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "GoogleApiClient connection failed: " + result.toString());
        if (!result.hasResolution()) {
            // Show a localized error dialog.
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(
                    result.getErrorCode(), this, 0, new OnCancelListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                            retryConnecting();
                        }
                    }
            ).show();
            return;
        }
        // If there is an existing resolution error being displayed or a resolution
        // activity has started before, do nothing and wait for resolution
        // progress to be completed.
        if (mIsInResolution) {
            return;
        }
        mIsInResolution = true;
        try {
            result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_CODE_RESOLUTION);
        } catch (SendIntentException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception while starting resolution activity", e);
            retryConnecting();
        }
    }

    private void saveFileToDrive() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Creating new contents.");
        Drive.DriveApi.newContents(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(mSaveFileCallback);
    }

    private void showMessage(String message) {
        Log.i(TAG, message);
//        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private class EditFileAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<DriveApi.ContentsResult, Void, Boolean> {

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(DriveApi.ContentsResult... params) {
            DriveApi.ContentsResult contentsResult = params[0];
            if (!contentsResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                showMessage("Failed to create new contents.");
                return false;
            }
            showMessage("New contents created.");
            OutputStream outputStream = contentsResult.getContents().getOutputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            mBitmapToSave.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, bitmapStream);
            try {
                outputStream.write(bitmapStream.toByteArray());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                showMessage("Unable to write file contents.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            MetadataChangeSet metadataChangeSet = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                    .setMimeType("image/jpeg")
                    .setTitle("some_image.jpg")
                    .build();

            IntentSender intentSender = Drive.DriveApi
                    .newCreateFileActivityBuilder()
                    .setInitialMetadata(metadataChangeSet)
                    .setInitialContents(contentsResult.getContents())
                    .build(mGoogleApiClient);

            try {
                startIntentSenderForResult(intentSender, REQUEST_CODE_CREATOR, null, 0, 0, 0);
            } catch (SendIntentException e) {
                showMessage("Failed to launch file chooser.");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            if (!result) {
                showMessage("Error while editing contents");
                return;
            }
            showMessage("Successfully edited contents");
        }
    }
}
```

- By the way, most of the code in this class was auto-generated by Android Studio, because when I created the project I marked the initial class to be a google services class.

Answer (score 1):

It,s simple. After I trying hard, I found the solution.

```
private String mFileName = null;
File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + 
"/FolderFile");
    if (!folder.exists()) {
        folder.mkdir();
    }
mFileName = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    mFileName += "/FolderFile/a.mp3";
```

After the audio is recorded. You must 
[buildGoogleSignInClient()](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth#connecting_and_authorizing_the_google_drive_android_api)

```
createFileWithIntent(mFileName);

private void createFileWithIntent(String I) {
     final String audio = I;
    final Task<DriveFolder> rootFolderTask = getDriveResourceClient().getRootFolder();
    final Task<DriveContents> createContentsTask = getDriveResourceClient().createContents();
    Tasks.whenAll(rootFolderTask, createContentsTask)
            .continueWithTask(new Continuation<Void, Task<DriveFile>>() {
                @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
                public Task<DriveFile> then(@NonNull Task<Void> task) throws Exception {
                    DriveFolder PASTA = rootFolderTask.getResult();
                    DriveContents DADOS = createContentsTask.getResult();

                    File file = new File(audio);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
                        baos.write(buf, 0, readNum);
                    }
                    OutputStream outputStream = DADOS.getOutputStream();
                    outputStream.write(baos.toByteArray());

                    MetadataChangeSet TIPO = new MetadataChangeSet.Builder()
                            .setMimeType("audio/mp3")
                            .setTitle("audio.mp3")
                            .setStarred(true)
                            .build();


                    return getDriveResourceClient().createFile(PASTA, TIPO, DADOS);
                }
            });

}
```